# Convert EPOCH time in CSV file (CentOS)

Tags: awk, centos, epoch

I would like to know how to find and then convert/replace the EPOCH time from a .CSV to human readable format. The CSV contains thousands of rows each following the same format structure as below.

`54383,1,A9,6,13,0,600,0,"",,0,0,1492674758,192.168.215.52,FA:C1:3F:00:43:97,1492674787,0,0,0,0,,""`

So our target columns are 13 and 16 if I read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

with `gawk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=","  '{$13=strftime("%c",$13);$16=strftime("%c",$16)};1' file.csv
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you, it worked! I have another question: once the date has been changed, if the log contained 7 days of logs, how would I grep just the last 24 hours from the last entry? It seems that both columns contain the same times so really we could use column 13 time and look back 24 hours?